# save strings to string.xml, Android

Tags: android, string, save

I'm trying to create a way to get input from a user and save the string in the string.xml, so that when I launch my Application again, it will be there. Can I use the string.xml or do I have to save it another way?

Answer (score 3):

> Can I use the string.xml or do I have to save it another way?

You will have to do something different. The `resources` can't be changed after it has been compiled.

Have a look at [Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) to see which way is best for you. The best way will be determined by things such as the type and amount of data you will be storing.

The link I posted sums it up pretty well then you can dig into the structures that you think might work best for your situation. From the link:

> Shared Preferences
> Store private primitive data in key-value pairs.
>
> Internal Storage
> Store private data on the device memory.
>
> External Storage
> Store public data on the shared external storage.
>
> SQLite Databases
> Store structured data in a private database.
> Network Connection
> Store data on the web with your own network server.

Comment: If it's a lot, then use a db.

Answer (score 0):

in order to save your strings you can use **SharedPreferences**

to save your data

```
SharedPreferences pos;
public String fileName = "file";

pos = getSharedPreferences(fileName, 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pos.edit();
editor.putString("pwd","your string");      
editor.commit();
```

to get your data

```
pos = getSharedPreferences(fileName, 0);
String data = pos.getString("pwd", "");
```